how to install highlightjs
I'am tryng to install highlightjs in my angular project. I followed these instructions :
but when i try to add this in my app.config.ts
  providers: [
    provideHighlightOptions({
      fullLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js')
    })
  ]

I get an error:  Cannot find module 'highlight.js' or its corresponding type declarations.ts
enter image description here
I'm trying to solve the problem to fully install highlightjs.

does angular throw any errors in console?

The problem is resolved by installing highlight.js. It's not mentioned in the doc.

You must also install the highlight.js library. Their docs are not clear of this but their Stackblitz led me to infer.
npm install highlight.js
https://github.com/highlightjs/
Highlightjs Demo stackblitz
